# Route all traffic through a VPN using the OpenWRT firmware

Tags: openwrt

I have a home network with a number of wireless clients, including laptops, a media server, and some consoles.

Just 4 days ago my world changed: My the country i live in signed in to ACTA.
As i refuse to take part in this personal assault of a legislation, i want to route all of my traffic through a VPN to another country where this problem does not exist.

I'd like to accomplish this using the openWRT firmware, which i have successfully installed on a Netgear N600 wlan router.

I see a number of docs explaining how to use openWRT as an openVPN server, but none on how to use it as a openVPN client.

Could anybody be so kind and explain how to achieve a setup where either the VPN is up and running, or i am cut out of the internet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: [OpenVPN Termination on OpenWrt](http://martybugs.net/wireless/openwrt/openvpn.cgi), it is a different router, but should be similar

Comment: <standard comment about not just posting links without explanation>